# How to fix invisible margin parameter?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

for first i am really bad with css! I have strange problems... but firstly let me show you my app
Here is screen: (left sidebar expanded)
[image]

(left sidebar hidden)
[image]

Please take a look on scrollbar around that canvas covered with grid. This scrollbar look like that because it have margin-top and margin-left = 20. Look at this:
[image]

If i will delete this margin in that place, look how it will be look like:
[image]

As you can see everything look good. I needed to show you that with debbuger on my left side because if i close him then immediatly this margin come back. I needed to show that with debugger on my right side because if i close him then immediately this margin come back. Here is my code of that "grid" part:

```
<div id="justdraw" style="position: static; width: 1600px; height: 600px;">
    <!-- The Diagram component is bound to the canvas element below -->
    <div id="ruler" style="position: static; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <div id="canvas" style="position: absolute; width: 1600px; height: 600px; margin-top: 0; margin-left: 0; overflow: scroll">
            <canvas id="diagram" width="2100" height="2100">
                This page requires a browser that supports HTML 5 Canvas element.
            </canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using fragments Thymeleaf, that code is fragment and it is used here:

```
<!-- Page Content  -->
<div id="content" style="position: relative;">
    <th:block th:include="diagramER :: diagram"/>
</div>
```

**Can anyone tell me what could be the reason for this? How is it possible that the styles in the browser show something different than what I have in the code?**

Styles from browser:

```
element.style {
position: absolute;
width: 1600px;
height: 600px;
overflow: scroll;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Styles from my code:

```
<div id="canvas" style="position: absolute; width: 1600px; height: 600px; margin-top: 0; margin-left: 0; overflow: scroll">
```

Comment: Can you create a working example of your code in-snippet or code-pen

Comment: i am using some static libraries, but i will try

Comment: Thanks ,I think you are using bootstrap so you can create that

Comment: https://codepen.io/albert-kozera/pen/BayJJxr

thats all i can do without my static libraries. Its strange because here that scrollbar is without margin -.-

Comment: ok i figured it out. Thanks to builiding that example! 
This ruler (in my graphic library MindFusion) have parametr margin... And that imposed this value 20.

Comment: @Braoad Glad that helps to solve your problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's different on other OS'.. so you should style your scrollbar

Made a quick sample:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  display: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p4mc70go/1/